# Sybase SQL Dynamic Select (Joins?) Relational Database

Tags: sql, select, join, sybase, relational-database

I am writing a web page that displays students grades in an old grade book format which is to say, it displays the Student name, then their score for each assignment (in a row) then repeats one row per student.  My tables are set up as follows (shortened to necessary info):

Table: Assignment
 * Assignment_PK (Primary Key)
 * Assignment_Name

Table: Student
 * Student_PK (Primary Key)
 * Student_Name

Table: StudentAssignment
 * SA_PK (Primary Key
 * Student_FK (Student.Student_PK)
 * Assignment_FK (Assignment.Assignment_PK)
 * Score

I am trying to write a SELECT statement that will print the students name and score for each assignment.  The problem I'm running into is that if I SELECT Score as a column, I only get the score for one assignment because in my WHERE Assignment_FK = Assignment_PK only allows me to pick one Score for a column.

I'm fairly new to Relational Databases and I could really use some help on the best way to tackle this.  One suggestion was that I write a SELECT statement to pick all Students into a table, then do a foreach row in the table and have it select the scores and place them in the appropriate column.  This seems like a slow and unnecessary process.  Is there any easier way using JOINS?  Or writing a better SELECT?

Comment: look up PIVOT tables.  it is alot easier if you know the number of assignments ahead of time... (which is a big IF).

Comment: A PIVOT table was exactly what I needed. I can do an initial query to get the number of assignments ahead of time. Sybase does not have the PIVOT or TRANSFORM function built into it. Instead I had to load all my data and then wrote a C# Object to read in the data, transform and display it in the format I wanted. A PIVOT Table would have worked perfectly though, if Sybase supported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the data you need. You can then investigate pivoting it into the desired display format, which *may* be easier in your application than in the database.

```
SELECT s.Student_Name, a.Assignment_Name, sa.Score
    FROM Student s
        INNER JOIN StudentAssignment sa
            ON s.Student_PK = sa.Student_FK
        INNER JOIN Assignment a
            ON sa.Assignment_FK = a.Assignment_PK
    ORDER BY s.Student_Name, a.Assignment_Name
```